# ReactQuill + quill-mention tab key not behaving as expected

Tags: reactjs, input, keyboard-events, quill, react-quill

Preface: This question is related to a React component using [ReactQuill](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill) & [quill-mention](https://github.com/quill-mention/quill-mention), where the tab key doesn't behave as expected.

After pressing the tab key, the `p` element inside gets set to `0` height, resulting in the image below.

[image: When mention input is empty and tab is pressed, height gets set to 0]

2nd case is when I have some arbitrary value in the input, and then I press the tab key. As you can see, the foo in the console is the value of the component, to which the tab indent is added, but visually the text indicator doesn't move away from the `stackoverflow` string.

[image: When mention input has a value and tab is pressed]

Note how the issues are present without me using the mention module at all.

ReactQuill usage:

```
<ReactQuill
    className={twMerge(
        'h-full w-full',
        leadingIcon && 'border-0 pl-10'
    )}
    id={elementId}
    key={elementId}
    modules={modules} // toolbar is false, mention is defined to fit my case
    onChange={(foo) => {
        console.log('foo: ', foo);

        setValue(foo);
    }}
    onFocus={() => {
        if (editorRef.current) {
            setFocusedInput(editorRef.current);

            setDataPillPanelOpen(true);
        }
    }}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    ref={editorRef}
    value={value}
/>
```

I tried hijacking the `onKeyDown` event to disable tab, but that didn't work and it's not really the desired behavior. Also, I tried defining the `keyboard` module but also, that disables the tab key which is not something I'd want.

Other than that I haven't found anything else to try.

The desired behavior of the tab key is the same as in their official example - https://quill-mention.com/